# how to "php echo from python print"?

Tags: php, python

I am trying to get python matrix to php (struggling for resolving this problem for more than 20 hours). I would really appreciate for any help!

There are two cases below: TEST and REAL.

- TEST: A variable of php is passed to python. With the passed variable into python, a matrix value is explicitly assigned. This matrix should be called to php.
- REAL: A variable of php is passed to python. Along with the variable, one file is in-filed to python. Then, parsed value is assigned to matrix which should be called to php.

They have the exactly same output of python running as well as the same php code. The only difference is that in the REAL case, a file is in-filed to python script. TEST python itself works fine, REAL python itself works fine, TEST php-python running works fine, but REAL php-python running fails. So my guess is that php does not allow python to in-file into the python scripts?? My codes look like:

## =========== TEST CASE ===========

===== test.py

```
import os, sys, json
g = json.loads( sys.argv[1] )

gene = ['>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1', '>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1', '>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1']
gene.append(g)
seq = ["ATGGAC", "GGCACAGC", "CCACC"]
seq.append('ACTGAAA')

print json.dumps(output)
```

===== test.php

```
$output=null;
$g = "0.CUFF.6.1_2";
$data = escapeshellarg(json_encode($g));
exec("python /mysql/getSeq/test.py $data 2>&1 &", $output );
//exec("python /mysql/getSeq/test.py $data 2>&1", $output );   --> worked fine
//exec("python /mysql/getSeq/test.py $data", $output );   --> worked fine
//print_r($output);   --> worked fine
//var_dump($output);   --> worked fine

$result = json_decode( exec("python /mysql/getSeq/test.py $data", $output ) , true);
//print_r( $result);   --> worked fine 
//var_dump($result);   --> worked fine
echo $result[0][0] . "<br>";
echo $result[0][1] . "<br>";
echo $result[1][0] . "<br>";
echo $result[1][1] . "<br>";
```

===== results on the web page

```
>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1
ATGGAC
>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1
GGCACAGC
```

## =========== REAL CASE ===========

===== real.py

```
import os, sys, json

inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r")
g = json.loads( sys.argv[1] )

inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r")
line = inF.readline()
matrix = []
--- (some codes here) ---
inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r")
line = inF.readline()
gene = []
--- (some codes here) ---
for i in range(len(index)) : 
    output[i][0] = ">" + gene[i]
    output[i][1]= str(matrix[i])[2:-4]

print json.dumps(output)
# print output
```

===== real.php

```
$output=null;
$g = "0.CUFF.6.1_2";
$data = escapeshellarg(json_encode($g));
exec("python /mysql/getSeq/real.py $data  2>&1 &", $output );
//exec("python /mysql/getSeq/real.py $data  2>&1", $output );  --> no difference in results
//exec("python /mysql/getSeq/real.py $data", $output );   --> no difference in results
$result = json_decode( exec("python /mysql/getSeq/real.py $data 2>&1", $output ) , true);
print_r($output) . "<br>";
//var_dump($output) . "<br>";
//print_r( $result) . "<br>";
//var_dump($result) . "<br>";
//echo $result[0][0] . "<br>";
//echo $result[0][1] . "<br>";
//echo $result[1][0] . "<br>";
//echo $result[1][1] . "<br>";
```

===== results on the web page

print_r($output); --> error

```
Array ( [0] => Traceback (most recent call last): [1] => File "/mysql/getSeq/getOne.py", line 3, in [2] => inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r") [3] => IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getSeq_Mh.fasta' [4] => Traceback (most recent call last): [5] => File "/mysql/getSeq/real.py.py", line 3, in [6] => inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r") [7] => IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getSeq_Mh.fasta' )
```

var_dump($output); --> error

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(34) "Traceback (most recent call last):" [1]=> string(95) " File "/mysql/getSeq/getOne.py", line 3, in " [2]=> string(38) " inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r")" [3]=> string(63) "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getSeq_Mh.fasta'" [4]=> string(34) "Traceback (most recent call last):" [5]=> string(95) " File "/mysql/getSeq/real.py.py", line 3, in " [6]=> string(38) " inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r")" [7]=> string(63) "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getSeq_Mh.fasta'" }
```

print_r( $result); --> error

```
(nothing)
```

var_dump($result); --> error

```
NULL
```

## =========== PYTHON ITSELF ===========

```
[['>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1', 'ATGGACT'], ['>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1', 'GGCACAGC'], ['>MhA1_Contig0.frz3.gene1', 'CCACC']]
```

Comment: in `exec("python real.py $data", $output );` change this to: `exec("python real.py $data 2>&1", $output );` and then `print_r($output)` and see what errors you get.

Comment: For test files, it worked with all of the cases: " 2>&1 &" and "2>&1". However, for real files, the results shown on the web page look like: "Array ( [0] => Traceback (most recent call last): [1] => File "/mysql/getSeq/getOne.py", line 3, in [2] => inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r") [3] => IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getSeq_Mh.fasta' [4] => Traceback (most recent call last): [5] => File "/mysql/getSeq/getOne.py", line 3, in [6] => inF = file("getSeq_Mh.fasta", "r") [7] => IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'getSeq_Mh.fasta' )".

Comment: It seems that the command line of reading file in python scripts might be the problem. Will there be other solutions?

Comment: You could try mimicking your command line $PATH variables in `putenv` like so: `putenv("PATH=/usr/bin/local;/usr/bin; ....")`  This solved problems for me, also in the python script, I needed to make all paths absolute to the directory because where it calls the file is different than the location of the file itself, causing directory, permissions and read issues.  Looks like you found your problem though with the answer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PHP's [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to handle child processing (input/output); here the child process being the Python script. Below calls Python at command line, passing `$data` argument and receiving the `$output` parameter.

Two assumptions are made that may need adjustment on your end: *python* is a path variable on your server and Python script is in same directory as PHP script. If not, insert full path to *python.exe* in command line and/or insert full path of directory to *real.py* in command line.

```
$output=null;
$g = "0.CUFF.6.1_2";
$data = escapeshellarg(json_encode($g));

$cd = dirname(__FILE__);                       // CURRENT DIRECTORY OF SCRIPT
$output = null;

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("file", $cd."/error.txt", "a")   // ERROR TXT OUTPUT OF PROCESSING
);

/* CALLING COMMAND LINE */
$process = proc_open("python \"$cd/real.py\" \"$data\"" , $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cd); 

/* RECEIVING OUTPUT */
$output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
proc_close($process);

echo $output;
```

Comment: $cd means: If python file is located in /mysql/getSeq/, then $cd = "/mysql/getSeq"; . Is this right? But nothing on the web page.

Comment: The `$cd` variable is path of PHP script (not Python script unless it is in same folder). It is not really needed for `proc_open` but included for shortened command line.

Comment: What if PHP and PYTHON scripts are located in different directory? Since there is another file which should be in-filed to python, that file and python scripts are located together in another cluster.

Comment: Then change `$cd` in command line to absolute path of directory: `proc_open("python \"/path/to/real.py\" \"$data\"",...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. When I put all the files ("real.py", "real.php", and "getSeq_Mh.fasta(which is in-filed to real.py)") in the same directory, it worked.

Thanks, Parfait. Your commend gave me a hint.